# PHP foreach loop force certain children to be at top

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the below `foreach` loop running over an array of WooCommerce products, which are queried by the below query. This outputs the products in the `menu_order`, which is as expected, however what I need to do is to keep them in this order, EXCEPT products which as 'featured products'. These should almost be ignored by the order parameter and always appear first in the `foreach` loop.

Is this possible?

```
// Get Products
$args = array(
  'status' => 'publish',
  'category' => $currentCat->slug,
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'limit' => -1,
);
$productsData = wc_get_products( $args );

<? // For each product
foreach($productsData as $product): ?>
        
  <? if( $product['isFeatured'] ): ?>
    // Output featured product html here...
  <? else: ?>
    // Output other products HTML here...
  <? endif ?>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: I have GOT to go to bed but look up "sticky" products and you should find some answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this for my needs by performing 2 separate queries, and then merging them into an array (in the desired order). This ensures one query always appears before the other, whilst each query can still respect ordering parameters such as `menu_order`.

```
// Featured products query
$featuredArgs = array(
  'status' => 'publish',
  'category' => $currentCat->slug,
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'limit' => 1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
      'field'    => 'name',
      'terms'    => 'featured',
      'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
  ),
);

// Non-featured products query
$nonFeaturedArgs = array(
  'status' => 'publish',
  'category' => $currentCat->slug,
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'limit' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
      'field'    => 'name',
      'terms'    => 'featured',
      'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    ),
  ),
);

// Get products from each query (performed seperately so that we can control the order of products)
$featuredProductsData = wc_get_products( $featuredArgs );
$nonFeaturedProductsData = wc_get_products( $nonFeaturedArgs );

// Merge both queries in the desired order
$productsData = array_merge($featuredProductsData, $nonFeaturedProductsData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but you could see if this works. I know this trick works with meta queries, so It might work with taxonomy queries too: the trick being to reference the tax queries by name in the orderby.

```
$featured_tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
    'field'    => 'name',
    'terms'    => 'featured',
    'operator' => 'IN',
);
$non_featured_tax_query = $featured_tax_query;
$non_featured_tax_query['operator'] => 'NOT IN';

$args = array(
  'status' => 'publish',
  'category' => $currentCat->slug,
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'limit' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array('featured' => $featured_tax_query,
                       'non_featured' => $non_featured_tax_query),
  'orderby' => array(
    'featured' => 'ASC',
    'non_featured' => 'ASC',
  )
);
$featuredProductsData = wc_get_products( $args );
```

If the above doesn't work, you can break it out into 2 different queries like so:

```
$tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
    'field'    => 'name',
    'terms'    => 'featured',
    'operator' => 'IN',
);

// Get featured products
$args = array(
  'status' => 'publish',
  'category' => $currentCat->slug,
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'limit' => -1,
  'tax_query' => $tax_query,
);
$featuredProductsData = wc_get_products( $args );

foreach($featuredProductsData as $product): ?>
    // Output featured product html here...
<?php endforeach; ?>

// Get non-featured products
$tax_query['operator'] => 'NOT IN';
$args['tax_query'] => $tax_query;
$productsData = wc_get_products( $args );

foreach($productsData as $product): ?>
    // Output other products HTML here...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Hey @wp-overwatch.com - thanks for these 2 options. I think the top option looks really promising, but currently doesn't quite work. Where do the 'featured' and 'non_featured' names come from? At present, the 2 individual tax_querys work on their own, but not when combined using the 'featured' and 'non_featured' names?